# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ionic-angular@3.7.1

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've been stuck with this dependency error. I've searched about this but none of the solutions worked for me.
Can't get this dependencies problem solved.
Already tried to change versions on package.json

Already tried to update ionic-angular version to 3.9.0

Error that i'm getting:

```
├── @ionic-native/file@4.11.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ionic-angular@3.7.1

npm WARN ionic-img-viewer@2.9.0 requires a peer of ionic-angular@~3.9.0 but none was installed.
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/intercom": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "cordova-android": "~6.3.0",
    "cordova-ios": "~4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-intercom": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.15",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ios-deploy": "git+https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy.git",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-intercom": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for your precious time!